# Storing images from server in GAE blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to store files and images that I get from an api in the blobstore (or rather so that they are accessible from the blobstore api). Since the file-api is deprecated, how do I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - have you tried to ask any GAE official support channel?

Comment: I have same the topic, from many suggestion it is advisable to use GCS to store image rather than Datastore or Blobstore.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store images in Cloud Storage (gcs) and access them via the blogstore api. Basically you call `gcs.open()` and write the file. Then when you need to use the blobstore api you call `blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key()`. With that you can do things such as use the images api with calls like `images.get_serving_url(blobkey, secure_url=False)`.

How you do that depends on what you're particular goals are. I am using to serve images in a gallery that I upload. To do that I have an file upload on an html form on the front end, which sends the file. On the backend I am doing this (these are just the broad strokes):

```
#  inside the webapp2.RequestHandler get method:
import mimetypes
file_data = self.request.get("photoUpload", default_value = None)
filename = self.request.POST["photoUpload"].filename
folder = "someFolderName"
content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(self.filename)[0]
```

Then save the file data to GCS:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import cloudstorage as gcs

# gcs_filename must be unique so I'm using bucket/folder/file
# it would be smart to check uniqueness before proceeding
gcs_filename = '/%s%s/%s' % (bucket or app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(), folder, filename)
gcs.open(gcs_filename, 'w', content_type=content_type or b'binary/octet-stream', options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
            f.write(file_data)
```

Now I can access using the GCS api with calls like:

```
gcs.delete(gcs_filename)
```

Or use the Blobstore API by getting the previously mentioned blocky:

```
blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key()
```